# trying to update nested array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, monodevelop

```css
`  "id": 1,
  "name": "Afghanistan",
  "iso3": "AFG",
  "iso2": "AF",
  "states": [
    {
      "id": 3901,
      "name": "Badakhshan",
      "state_code": "BDS",
      "latitude": "36.73477250",
      "longitude": "70.81199530",
      "type": null,
      "cities": [
        {
          "id": 52,
          "name": "Ashkāsham",
          "latitude": "36.68333000",
          "longitude": "71.53333000"
        },
```

```js
 dbo.collection("countries").updateOne(myquery, 
  { $set: { "states.$[].cities.$[filter].name": new_name } },
    { arrayFilters: [  {"filter.name":old_city_name} ] },
        async function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ success: false, response: err.message, statusbar: err })
      }
       res.json({ success: true, statuscode: 200, response: result });
      db.close();
    });
```

trying to update a city name which in the states array its working but its updating every city in that particular state need some help guys
tq all

Comment: your query seems to work as expected: https://mongoplayground.net/p/IGbPfcJUPHd

Comment: "but its updating every city in that particular state"  What do you want?

Comment: I just rebooted the server and its working I don't understand how it is possible tq  @R2D2